# How to access the results of .match as string value in Crystal lang

Tags: regex, matching, crystal-lang

In many other programming languages, there is a function which takes as a parameter a regular expression and returns an array of string values. This is true of Javascript and Ruby. The `.match` in crystal, however, does 1) not seem to accept the global flag and 2) it does not return an array but rather a struct of type `Regex::MatchData`. (https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/Regex/MatchData.html)

As an example the following code:

```
str = "Happy days"
re = /[a-z]+/i
matches = str.match(re)
puts matches
```

returns `Regex::MatchData("Happy")`

I am unsure how to convert this result into a string or why this is not the default as it is in the inspiration language (Ruby). I understand this question probably results from my inexperience dealing with structs and compiled languages but I would appreciate an answer in hopes that it might also help someone else coming from a JS/Ruby background.

Comment: It seems you want `matches.string`, but with [`scan`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.20.1/String.html#scan%28pattern%3ARegex%29-instance-method), you will get all matches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What if I want to convert to a string merely **the first match**?

```
puts "Happy days"[/[a-z]+/i]?
puts "Happy days".match(/[a-z]+/i).try &.[0]
```

It will try to match a string against `/[a-z]+/i` regex and if there is a match, Group 0, i.e. the whole match, will be output. Note that the `?` after `[...]` will make it fail gracefully if there is no match found. If you just use `puts "??!!"[/[a-z]+/i]`, an exception will be thrown.

See [this online demo](https://tio.run/##Sy6qLC5JzPn/v6C0pFhBySOxoKBSISWxslgpWj86UbcqVls/M9aeCyJrb6@oiE0cSZdebmJJcoYGXI2mXklRpYKaXrRBLNf//wA).

If you want the functionality similar to `String#scan` that returns **all matches found in the input**, you may use (shortened version only left as per [@Amadan's remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391997/how-to-access-the-results-of-match-as-string-value-in-crystal-lang/51392086?noredirect=1#comment89756715_51392086)):

```
str = "Happy days"
re = /[a-z]+/i
matches = [] of String
str.scan(re) do |match|
      matches << match[0]
    end
puts matches
```

Output of the [code above](https://tio.run/##Sy6qLC5JzPn/v7ikSMFWQckjsaCgUiElsbJYiasoFSiiH52oWxWrrZ/JlZtYkpyRWgwUi45VyE9TCC4pysxL5wJq1CtOTszTKErVVEjJV6gBq6vhUgADmCYbGwhTrxiiCySXmpfCVVBaUgxT9P8/AA):

```
["Happy", "days"]
```

Note that [`String::scan`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.20.1/String.html#scan%28pattern%3ARegex%29-instance-method) will return an array of [`Regex::MatchData`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.20.1/Regex/MatchData.html) for each match. To get the text of the match, just access the first item in the match object.

A shorter way is to use

```
matches = str.scan(re).map(&.to_a).flatten
```

See the [online demo](https://tio.run/##Sy6qLC5JzPn/v7ikSMFWQckjsaCgUiElsbJYiasoFSiiH52oWxWrrZ/JVVBaUqwAVKZXnJyYp1GUqqmXm1igoaZXkh@fqKmXlpNYUpKa9/8/AA).

Comment: Or simpler, `matches = str.scan(re).map(&.string)`

Comment: @Amadan Yes, sure, I was going to add that, too, but fell asleep :( It was like 2:30 AM :)

Comment: What if I want to convert to a string merely the first match? `puts match.string` will print `Happy days` while I would like to print just `Happy`. Meanwhile `puts match` yields `Regex::MatchData("Happy") `

Comment: @Shadow43375 I added two variations at the top of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the posted example returns a `#<MatchData "Happy">` in Ruby, which also has no "global" flag – thats what [`String#scan(Regex)`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/String.html#scan%28pattern%3ARegex%29-instance-method) is for as mentioned by others.

If you want only a *single* match without going through `Regex::MatchData`, you can use [`String#[](Regex)`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/String.html#%5B%5D%28regex%3ARegex%2Cgroup%29-instance-method):

```
str = "Happy days"
p str[/[a-z]+/i] # => "Happy"
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment by [@Shadow43375](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8242496/shadow43375), the accepted answer only works if you need the first result.

If one want to obtain **all matches found in the input** you need to use the following code:

```
matches = str.scan(re).map{ |x| x[0] }
```

Output:

```
["Happy", "days"]
```

[Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) was wrong `Regex::MatchData.string` doesn't return the matched string but return the original string.

As he demonstrated himself, the output of

```
matches = str.scan(re).map(&.string)
```

is

```
["Happy days", "Happy days"]
```

cf. https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.7.2/Regex/MatchData.html#string%3AString-instance-method